# Sorting data in an array by keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Good day.

We have array:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    [1]=>
    string(12) "aaandroid.ru"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [7]=>
    string(5) "Test2"
    [8]=>
    string(10) "2012-03-27"
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2013-04-29"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(9) {
    [1]=>
    string(7) "aaga.ru"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "Test1"
    [8]=>
    string(10) "2008-02-21"
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2013-04-29"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(9) {
    [1]=>
    string(10) "aatrakc.ru"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "Test3"
    [8]=>
    string(10) "2012-03-27"
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2013-04-29"
  }
```

*Tell me please how sort data in array with key?*

For example i would like get array where data sorting on element 7, ie. in result i would like get array:

```
array(3) {
      [1]=>
      array(9) {
    [1]=>
    string(7) "aaga.ru"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [7]=>
    string(8) "Test1"
    [8]=>
    string(10) "2008-02-21"
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2013-04-29"
      }
    [1]=>
    string(12) "aaandroid.ru"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [7]=>
    string(5) "Test2"
    [8]=>
    string(10) "2012-03-27"
    [9]=>
    string(10) "2013-04-29"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(9) {
        [1]=>
        string(10) "aatrakc.ru"
        [2]=>
        string(1) "0"
        [3]=>
        string(1) "0"
        [4]=>
        string(1) "0"
        [5]=>
        string(1) "0"
        [6]=>
        string(1) "0"
        [7]=>
        string(8) "Test3"
        [8]=>
        string(10) "2012-03-27"
        [9]=>
        string(10) "2013-04-29"
      }
```

*Tell me please it really an how make it?*

Comment: `usort($myArray, function($a, $b) { if ($a[7] == $b[7]) { return 0; } return ($a[7] < $b[7]) ? -1 : 1; });`

Comment: how to sort the data in reverse order?

Answer (score 2):

Check the PHP `usort` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php.
It provides (in place) sorting based on a callback, which you can create.

Example:

```
usort($myArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a[7], $b[7]);
});
```

Comment: nice... tell me please how to sort the data in reverse order?

Comment: All you have to do is to switch the order of parameters in strcmp call.  strcmp($b[7], $a[7]);

Comment: @learner Please look at the documentation in the link I pointed to. Learn the function, and you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing Hidde's answer, if you want to reverse the order of the sort you would still use `usort()`, but you reverse the order of the parameters in the call to `strcmp()`. This will reverse which of the two arrays `usort()` sees as the larger value.

```
usort($myArray, function ($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($b[7], $a[7]);
});
```

This uses an anonymous function, so it will only work on Php 5.3 or later. If you have to work on 5.2 define a function to use as the callback.

```
function mySortFunction($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($b[7], $a[7]);
}

usort($myArray, 'mySortFunction');
```

See:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php